# create file with FileStream and apply FileAttributes

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, filestream, file-attributes

Is it possible while creating the file with FileStream also apply FileAttributes at the same time? I would like to create file for stream writing with FileAttributes.Temporary file attribute.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.filestream.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FileOptions.DeleteOnClose` as one of parameters. File will be automatically removed after you finish your operations and dispose a stream.

Comment: I am developing File Queue system and I use FileAttributes.Temporary as special attribute for queue actions. So when file is created for file streaming I would like to assign FileAttributes.Temporary imidiatlly.

Comment: Just look through overloads and you'll answer your question by yourself - There is no overload to set FileAttributes immediately. You could create an extension method if you want to do it in a one line, so you'll be able to use `using` construct and dispose the stream properly without using try..finally. So, why do you need it in a one line?

Answer (score -1):

Ya, surely you can apply FileAttributes also by using [`File.SetAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setattributes.aspx) Method

Comment: I want to do that at the same time when FileStream create the file. Does FileStream method has any possibilities to set FileAttributes?

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need to do it all at once?

1. Just create the file (using [File.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.create.aspx) or, if its a temporary file, use [GetTempFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx).)
2. [Set the attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setattributes.aspx) on the newly created file
3. Open the file using whatever method suits you

Answer (score -1):

You can do this if you use the Win32 CreateFile method

```
uint readAccess = 0x00000001;
uint writeAccess = 0x00000002;

uint readShare = 0x00000001;   

uint createAlways = 2;

uint tempAttribute = 0x100;
uint deleteOnClose = 0x04000000; 

new FileStream(new SafeFileHandle(NativeMethods.CreateFile("filename", 
                                                           readAccess | writeAccess, 
                                                           readShare, 
                                                           IntPtr.Zero, 
                                                           createAlways, 
                                                           tempAttribute | deleteOnClose, 
                                                           IntPtr.Zero), 
                                  true), 
               FileAccess.ReadWrite, 4096, true);


private static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern IntPtr CreateFile(string name, uint accessMode, uint shareMode, IntPtr security, uint createMode, uint flags, IntPtr template);
}
```

For more information, see the MSDN documentation of [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: why the downgrade ?